# switch to another IP on server when python requests goes out

Tags: python, linux, server, ip

i have a VPS which has 3 different IP addresses.
and i have a python script on it which crawl an specific website every 1 hour 
for example this is my python request:

```
 my_request = requests.get('https://example.com/timeline.json')
```

the only thing that i want is every time my python traffic goes out from the server  it uses that IP addresses randomly

Comment: @JavierBuzzi This may select a random address from a pool, but it does not help with _using_ that address in an outgoing request.

Comment: @JavierBuzzi ...What? `321.321.321.321` and `345.345.345.345` are absolutely not valid IPv4 addresses. Please read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4), before you give more people bad information.

Comment: @EhsanKordloo If you truly do have multiple public IP addresses, then this is a routing question and will not be configured on your VPS. But ensure that you are talking about public IP addresses, and not private IP addresses.

Comment: @arkascha OP changed the description, he made it seem originally that it was 3 fixed ips.

Comment: @vesche same, read the reply to arkascha. Also, i know they are bad ipv4 addresses, it was just an example, those werent his addresses to begin with, it was a place holder. Geez.

Comment: @JavierBuzzi I don't see what that should change.

Comment: @vesche This is _not_ a routing question. The OP asks about how it can be controlled which IP address is used in outgoing requests. That is a valid question.

Comment: Do you actually have 3 network adapters, so network interfaces setup and bound to those addresses? So you question is about which device is used? Or are you asking about how to change the address of a given interface?

Comment: @JavierBuzzi What? Regardless of the edit, your example was using blatantly incorrect IP addresses- and it's not like you can just pass a public IP in from a script.... Banging my head here.

Comment: @vesche i think the definition of a placeholder escapes you

Comment: @arkascha OP wants to use his IP's intermittently at the end server he is scraping. So if he really does have multiple public facing IP addresses, then he would need to route his traffic at whatever virtual infrastructure.

Comment: @JavierBuzzi It's extremely common to use placeholders for IP's... 1.2.3.4, for example. It's extremely uncommon and straight up wrong to use an invalid IP in an example.

Comment: @vesche yes sir, i have 3 public addresses ,so  how can i route my traffic randomly every time my request goes out from the server ?

Comment: You set up a load balancer in AWS, it's very easy, there's an icon for it in the Amazon console.

Comment: @JavierBuzzi Traffic originating from instances will not pass through a load balancer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after long deliberation in the comments, I can point you to some resources that hopefully will lead you to an answer. It's difficult to give a definitive answer to this question, because I'm unaware what kind of virtual infrastructure you are using or what the network looks like.

[Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/530783/multiple-outgoing-ip-on-one-amazon-ec2-instance) is a thread which had a similar desire, but was ultimately left unanswered. However, it is clear that if you are using AWS you will need to use [VPC](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/). And you would have to configure your ENI's in a special way to intermittently use your public IP addresses, to learn more about ENI's in VPC see [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html)

[This article](http://blackbird.si/vyatta-snat-randomly-rotating-public-ip-addresses/) details exactly what you are trying to accomplish, but using a Vyatta router with a special NAT configuration. There is a also mention of being able to accomplish this using advanced iptables rules, which might be worth looking into.

Regardless, you cannot accomplish delivering traffic using various public IP addresses from inside the script that is doing the crawling. To have this effect you will need to somehow modify the host network configuration in a special way (advanced iptable rules or periodically changing default routes), change the configuration of your virtual router (special NAT/routing rules), or using methods specific to your virtual hosting platform (Amazon VPC).